# In the output for netstat what does the [::] mean?

Tags: netstat

In the results for  netstat  what does the [::]  mean?

example

[::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, more specificially, it's equivalent to the IPv4 "0.0.0.0", which, when LISTEN is specified, means "any IP address."  You might also see "::1" which is the IPv6 loopback address.

In IPv6, a colon separates every 16 bits, or 4 hex digits.  However, consecutive zeroes in the address can be "collapsed" or omitted one time in any IPv6 address.  Even if the address is all zeroes.  So, for example, 2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 can be shortened down to just 2001::1.

So, evidently you have ssh listening and accepting connections from all IPv6 addresses.

Comment: On Linux, `::` will often listen for both IPv6 and IPv4 connections on the same socket.

Answer (score 5):

That it listens on an ipv6 interface.

Answer (score 4):

It means the service is listening to ipv6 connections. You do have *tcp6* in the beginning of that line, too, right?